# stop python process when waiting for user input

Tags: c#, python, user-input

I have a `C#`/`WPF` application that creates python code from drag-n-drop commands for non-programmers.

The resulting test is executed in a separate thread. One of those commands is a wrap around Python's `'raw_input'` (using Python2.6).

In some case, a user put this command inside a loop by accident and ran the resulting test. Since my application is waiting for his input, he can't use the application's usual stop command (since my app has opened another message box and is waiting for input).

Is there any way to enable users to stop the run in such a case? It can be either something in Python or a way to make the main window of the application responsive in such a case.

**Edit**
The `Python` code looks something like that:

```
for i in range(5):
    print "Labster7Information:i:Labster7Information"
    print i
    print "Labster7InputRequired:user input::Labster7InputRequired"
    s = str.strip(raw_input())
```

The `C#` code for creating the new window is just creating a `Window` with a `TextBox`. When it is shown, if I don't set its Owner property, I can see my main window, but it's not functional.

Comment: without any code provided, or any understanding of your localized application, i am not sure how anyone can help you. it seems to me that if you are creating these windows, you can also find a way to put a little button on them. or maybe have a little check that makes sure no one has raw_input inside a loop? or how about the good old fashioned alt-f4.

Comment: Em.. multithreading? Also, send 'return' symkey to the input.

Comment: I guess the user could just interrupt with `CTRL`+`C`

Comment: The good ole `alt+F4` closes the current input request window, but since it's in a loop, another one is opened straight away.